# Unstable Feedback in Opamp+MOSFET circuit for Voltage Controlled Current Source

Tags: current-source

I'm attempting to build a 1 Amp LASER driver that can be pulsed (at ~10kHz) and gives control over current with a voltage (from a DAC, for example). I'd like to scale it up to 10 Amp pulses eventually. I tried this common circuit below on a breadboard, but the feedback is unstable. Arrows indicate what *should* be (apprixmately) happening, which I confirmed on simulations.

I'm using a 500 mOhm 10 W resistor to simulate LAESR diode on resistance, and a 1 Ohm sense resistor.

[image]

Here is what happens at the opamp output:
[image]

And here is what happens at the inverting node (voltage across sense resistor):
[image]

I tried changing around the values but things only get worse. I thought the opamp was too wideband so I increased compensation cap C3. Feedback becomes stable when I make it 4.7uF (yes, 4.7uF), but pulsing Vctrl makes rise and fall times ~1s. Value of R3 doesn't seem to matter as long as it's there.

[This](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21685d.pdf) is the opamp I'm using (MCP6022, not 602), and [this](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irli3705npbf.pdf) is the FET I'm using (IRLI3705N). Is the opamp too wideband for this application? Its correcting too quickly and overshoots? Am I stuck at the "knee" on the FET's I-V curve so a little bit of gate voltage changes current exponentially? Is my Vcc not large enough? Is this even the right VCCS solution for a 10 A pulsed load?

Comment: It might not matter, but what kind of resistor are you using at R4?

Comment: 3 parallel 3.3 Ohm resistors (1%, 1/4W, E96) --> 1.1 Ohm that heats up mildly

Comment: Thanks to those who answered. But for anyone reading this in the future with the same issues: This was fixed by simply mounting this circuit on a perf/proto board. The parasitics on a the breadboard dominate even at currents as low as 100mA and cause instability. C4 was also removed.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. It will keep the question from rising up to the front page due to the system not knowing it's solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things can cause instability

1. With such low impedances you need to make sure you have a low inductance ground system.  Implementing this in a plug-in breadboard will probably not work, the parasitics are too high.
2. Remove C4 - it is possibly causing phase shift in your feedback loop.
3. You have a 22pF cap (C3) from the output of the amplifier to the input, but you have it directly connected to the 1 ohm sense resistor.  This will prevent it doing anything useful.  I would add a 1k resistor between the sense resistor and the inverting input of the opamp to isolate the stabilizing feedback path (C3) from the lower frequency signal from R4.  You may need to try different values for C3, I would expect you would need it much larger, maybe 1000's of pF.  You can get a good idea of what value you need by simulating it in LTspice. Have you simulated it?

kevin

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll try them out. Yes I did a time-domain simulation in CircuitLab and there was no oscillation. Hm, the breadboard might have a lot to do with it then.

Comment: Removing C4 and adding a resistor between C3 and the opamp did not do much, so I tried lowering the current by increasing the sense resistor R4 to 11 ohm. This eliminated the oscillation completely, which tells me inductive parasitics are dominating at large current loads.

Comment: But now when I pulse the control, the rise and fall times are still at ~1s. Adding a 1k pulldown at the gate does not help either. Is there anyway to reduce them 1000x?

Comment: R1 and C2 will limit the response time from the control signal.  They are not necessary for circuit operation.  If the input could be disconnected R2 can be retained but drive the input directly into the opamp.

Comment: 1 **second**? Surely not!

Comment: Actually, R1 and C2 were needed to prevent noise on the control voltage from causing instability. The opamp had enough bandwidth that fast voltage variations were causing current swings in the FET. But prototyping this on a perfboard rather than breadboard solved the problem...mostly.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points...

1. Monitor the 5V supply, just in case you're inducing instability in it - or the 300ish kHz signal you're seeing is actually its switching frequency.
2. Experiment with increasing R3 to at least 1 kilohm, thereby isolating the opamp output from a substantial load capacitance (Cgs of the MOSFET).

Now, even if increasing R3 cures the oscillation, it may not be the solution, because it decreases the bandwidth of the MOSFET drive (you can measure your pulse rise/fall times with and without the change, to determine if its effect is harmful). But there is a substantial body of literature on stabilising opamps driving capacitive loads, which should help you find a better solution.

Comment: So it turns out lowering current to ~100mA by increasing the sense resistor to 11ohm eliminates oscillation, which tells me inductive parasitics dominate at large current loads.

Comment: But you are right, the rise and fall times are still very long. Adding a 1k pull down at the gate does not help either. Can you provide some references or general techniques on opamps driving capacitive loads?

Comment: Nevermind, found something in the opamp datasheet, and lots on google.

Comment: The input capacitance of that (hugely parallel) MOSFET is 3500pF, which is asking a lot to be switched at 10KHz from an op-amp output. I wonder if a simple BJT driver could isolate the op-amp output and increase gate drive capability.

Answer (score 3):

Add a resistor between R4/M1 and the rest. 1K for starters, up to maybe 5 or 10K. Remove C4. You can increase C3 rather than the resistor value.

Comment: Especially remove C4.

Answer (score 0):

I used a same circuit for driving a laser diode with up to 500 mA current. I have some recommendations as follows:

- Use LM358 op amp
- Remove C2 and C4
- Use fast bipolar transistor for better stability such as D828